# VBA for extracting from URL

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to extracting the last page Number from URL, i want to gett tge maximum Number of pages.

bellow is my url

https://www.justdial.com/Upleta/Cosmetic-Wholesalers-in-Upleta-Lati-Plot

here bellow is VBA code i try but some where is problem

```
Dim sResponse As String, html As HTMLDocument
Dim url As String
Dim N As Long
Dim X As Long


        url = ActiveCell.Value
        With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
            .Open "GET", url, False
            .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
            .send
            sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
        End With
        Set html = New HTMLDocument

        With html
            .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) = .getElementByClass("Jpag").innerText
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) = .getElementById("srchpagination").innerText
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
        End With
```

please anybody help me out

Comment: What is the problem you're facing exactly? Does the code run but the result is wrong, or does the code fail at some point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can collect a nodeList of the pagination links and then take the last but one index i.e. the max page number. You can do this with a CSS descendant combinator to target the id of the parent element and then the `a` tag elements within. I use a -2 to get the correct index as the nodeList is 0 based indexing.

```
Debug.Print html.querySelectorAll("#srchpagination a").item(html.querySelectorAll("#srchpagination a").Length - 2).innerText
```

Comment: Hi QHarr i try following code        Set html = New HTMLDocument
          
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) = html.querySelectorAll("#srchpagination a").Item(html.querySelectorAll("#srchpagination a").Length - 2).innerText
      
)

Comment: hi QHarr please can you tell me how i can get last page Number in Pagination links in to excel... here is my URL         "https://www.justdial.com/Upleta/Cosmetic-Wholesalers"